# Is this a photo or 3D render, and how would I give a photo a similar effect?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, actions, photography

Is this a photo or rendered image?
[image]

How can I achieve a similar affect post production with a photo?  Are there any actions already available that might do this?

EDIT:

After comments below, are there any 3D tutorials that show how to create a photo with this look? 2D to 3D tutorials I've seen create videos or real 3Ds that you need the glasses for.

Comment: Post a regular link to the file, not a shortened one.  Many people are wary of clicking on blind links.

Comment: I assume you're asking if it's a photo vs. a rendering. It looks like a rendering to me. The effect would be utilizing a variety of 3d modeling, shading and lighting tools.

Comment: I can confirm it's a 3D rendering (http://vsha.cgsociety.org/gallery/422289/). The color treatment is however done in PS according to the artist. The volumetric light is a little bit hard to replicate in PS though.

Comment: This question needs to be more specific to give meaningful answers.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by "are there any 3D tutorials that show how to create a photo with this look?". Why would there be? You then mention "2D to 3D tutorials". This question would be a lot better if you clearly stated what you are trying to achieve, where you are now and what your specific problem is.

Comment: @e100: Sorry but this is probably an area your not familiar with.  Some comments below have answered my questions.

Comment: See this photos. These looks like a 3D render. https://www.dailysabah.com/gallery/not-arrakis-but-spain-la-palma-covered-in-ash-as-volcano-spews-on/images?gallery_image=68878

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The colour treatment? You can do most of that with a Gradient Map. In the example below, I'm using a Gradient Map that's set to 80% opacity.

### With a Gradient Map

[image]

### Without a Gradient Map

[image]

(Image nabbed from [here](http://www.travelcentre.com.au/travel/russia/Information/moscow_stpetersburg_train.htm).)

Comment: Would coloring be done in Photoshop first then bring it into the 3D program?

Comment: I think it's far more likely that the entire scene and lighting was rendered first, and Photoshop was used for post processing.

Answer (score 2):

It is a 3D render.

Google image search turns up the creator [Marcel Haladej at CgSociety.com](http://vsha.cgsociety.org/gallery/422289/)

Excellent image if you look at the [Full size](http://features.cgsociety.org/newgallerycrits/g10/251410/251410_1287158133_large.jpg).

Comment: Thanks on that link.  He mentioned vray and Digital Fusion.  Is this the vray he is referring to http://www.spot3d.com?  There are several hits of Digital Fusion.  I'm not sure of their site.

Comment: Great 3D work there.  Note however that just because this is a 3D render doesn't mean you can't get the exact same colour treatment with a photo.  As Marc's answer reveals, a gradient map is just one way of going about this (I'd wanna give it a bit more saturation there Marc).  Plus you'll wanna give it some [bloom](http://www.oferz.com/Tutorials/BloomEffect/BloomEffect.html).

Comment: @4thSpace Yep. V-Ray is a renderer that can be used with quite a few different 3D apps / 3D modellers. It's considered to be one of the best.

Comment: @thomasrutter: That bloom effect almost looks like it removes the need for anything 3D.  If just that effect were applied to the above photo and no 3D, how different do you think the two would be?

Comment: @Marc: Do you think V-Ray is really needed to get the same look?  I wonder if the gradient map + bloom effect can achieve it.

Comment: @4thSpace well clearly the 3D rendering has also had a bloom effect applied which is why I mentioned it.  You could certainly get a similar effect on a photo, yes.  You probably want the "hard light" variant or a combination of mostly "hard light", some "soft light".

Comment: Thanks.  Is there some name for this style/genre of photo?

Answer (score 1):

Although I am not sure exactly what you mean, if I wanted to achieve this effect, I would:

- Make the brights brighter and darks darker via levels or contrast
- Drop the saturation a bit
- And possibly add a grunge texture to make it more gritty

Hope this helped!